# What is the staetment used to fetch the authenthication token from the FB ???FB -android

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, android-facebook

I am using android studio for development .I was able to integrate my app with FB . 
I  want to fetch the auth-token token from the FB api . I am using FB apk 3.6 ..Can u kindly tell me the statement which is used to fetch the auth token ??

Answer (score 0):

Here it is:

```
Session.getActiveSession().getAccessToken()
```